# Js dynamic object with dynamic arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am creating dynamic filter like this

Filter 1
--property 1
--property 2
--property 3

Filter 2
--property 1
--property 2
--property 3

Thats the code

```
    var js_filter = {};
    var creators_cat = [];

    $('.filter-item input').on('change',function (e) {
        var filter_type = $(this).attr('name');
        var filter_term = $(this).val();
        creators_cat.push( filter_term );
        js_filter["'"+filter_type+"'"] = creators_cat;
        console.log(js_filter);
    })
```

and that's a response I get

```
{'filter-product_cat[]': Array(4), 'filter-brands': Array(4)}
'filter-brands': (4) ['32', '29', '23', '36']
'filter-product_cat[]': (4) ['32', '29', '23', '36']
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

as you can see array keys are dynamically added but values are the same for both of the keys.

An I need to add these separately.
Been looking for answer for quiet some time and didn't find something similar.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Why are you adding explicit quotes around `filter_type`?

Comment: There's only one `creators_cat` array, it's the value of both properties.

Comment: If you want to make a copy of the array for each property, use `[...creators_cat]`

Comment: The goal is to create it dynamically
Add values by key 
like so 

`filter-brands: (5) ['29', '23', '22']
filter-product_cat[]: (5) [  '36', '37' ]`

so instead of creators_cat there should be dynamic array.

Like in PHP I could add `$var[$key] = $value`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be pushing onto a global array. Each filter input should have its own array of values.

Check if there's already an element of the `js_filter` object for the current filter_type. If not, create it as an empty array. Then push the current value onto the array.

```
$('.filter-item input').on('change', function(e) {
  var filter_type = $(this).attr('name');
  var filter_term = $(this).val();
  if (!js_filter[filter_type]) {
    js_filter[filter_type] = [];
  }
  js_filter[filter_type].push(filter_term);
  console.log(js_filter);
})
```

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

Comment: Sorry, left out `!` in the test.

Comment: well that works ! Thank you!